# How to change color of selected UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having `UICollectionView` with 10 cells. When the view loads all the cells will be loaded with transparent images.

Now when the user chooses a specific `UICollectionViewCell`, how to change that cell color, and remaining cells will have the default background color.

Comment: Keep a var to know which index to color, then when you encounter it in cellForItemAtIndexPath, change the color, else put the transparent color because cells are reused? Also, in didSelect if needed?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, Larme.

Answer (score 3):

You should subclass `UICollectionViewCell`, change your cell to be of that subclass, and there override `setSelected:`. For example:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    if ( selected ) { // Selected cell
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else { // Normal cell
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
}
```

In Swift:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected { // Selected cell
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else { // Normal cell
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need UIcollectionView cell not in TableView. And fyi, Could you give me example in swift. Ivan

Comment: @HemanthAlluri yeah, I just noticed that, but the setter/variable is the same. Just be sure to subclass `UICollectionViewCell`. I already added the Swift example.

Comment: @Ivan, One more problem I'm facing is, while collectionView is loading it's first cell is automatically selected. Could you please tell me about this issue.

Comment: That's a completely different question, you should open a new question for that (or, even better, try to find that problem on StackOverflow).

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? Did you set the class of your `UICollectionViewCell` in the identity inspector?